# How do I get the maximum date (in YYYYMM format) from an array of dates in java?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to find out the largest date from an array of dates in `yyyyMM` format. For example, suppose my arraylist of dates are:

```
["202210", "202211", "202212", "202301"]
```

then the correct value should be `202301`

I tried using the `SimpleDateFormat` class and then parse the dates and then find the max date, like this:

```
List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("202210", "202211" ,"202212", "202301");  
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM", Locale.getDefault());
List<Date> temp = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    for (String date: dates) {
        temp.add(sdf.parse(date));
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(Collections.max(temp)); //shows Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2023
```

How do I convert the `Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2023` to `202301`?

Comment: If they are strings you can just get the biggest one: `Collections.max(dates)`

Comment: Please don't use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: `System.out.println(Collections.max(temp))` will use the `toString()` of `java.util.Date`, which doesn't use your desired format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the array is of String type, you can simply find largest string in chronological order and use that. Your current logic to find the max will still work or you can use some `Collection` to do that for you.

It will give you correct result since your format is `yyyyMM` which means a later year will always be larger than string value of a smaller year.

E.g. "202210" will always be less than "202211" or "202301"

Treating them as String will also save you computational time to parse them into `Date` object.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to display the max date in the same original format as the list, you need not convert to a bona fide date, assuming the date strings are always in the format `yyyyMM`.  In this case, the strings will sort properly as dates, and we can simply use `Collections#max` directly:

```java
List<String> dates=Arrays.asList("202210","202211","202212","202301"); 
System.out.println(Collections.max(dates));  // 202301
```

Answer (score 2):

You can — of course — sort the `String`s and get the last value, but if you want to use something comparable that represents a month in a year, use a `java.time.YearMonth`, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example values
    String[] monthsWithYears = { "202210","202211","202212","202301" };
    // formatter capable of the String format
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM");
    // map to list of YearMonth and find the maximum
    YearMonth maxYearMonth = Arrays.stream(monthsWithYears)
                                   .map(s -> YearMonth.parse(s, dtf))
                                   .max(YearMonth::compareTo)
                                   .get();
    // print it(s toString() method implicitly)
    System.out.println("Max year month is " + maxYearMonth);
}
```

Output:

```
Max year month is 2023-01
```

Comment: I recommend using the modern date-time API as suggested in this answer. @deHaaar - Simplify it as `YearMonth maxYearMonth = Arrays.stream(monthsWithYears)
                                       .map(s -> YearMonth.parse(s, dtf))
                                       .max(YearMonth::compareTo)
                                       .get();` i.e. you need not first collect it and then find the max value. Also, add one more step. `String strMaxYm = dtf.format(maxYearMonth);`. This step is important so that the OP can get the desired value in the input form.

Comment: Totally right, my example can be simplified! Thanks, @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: Much more beautiful than the other suggestions. The OP should use the correct type as shown here Even better keep `YearMonth` objects rather than strings in the list. For getting output in the desired format use `maxYearMonth.format(dtf)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the last line `System.out.println(Collections.max(temp));` to `System.out.println(sdf.format(Collections.max(temp)));`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using only a simple for-loop to determine the largest value with string comparison:

```java
List<String> dates=Arrays.asList("202210","202211","202212","202301");
String max = "000000";
for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
    if (dates.get(i).compareTo(max) > 0) {
        max = dates.get(i);
    }
}

System.out.println("Max date is: " + max); //Max date is: 202301
```